# @AspectJ. Pointcut for scala (and probably java) lambdas

Tags: java, scala, aspectj

Is it possible to have poitcut for scala lambdas? If I'm not mistaken scala lambdas now compiled in the same way as java lambdas, so I think my question is also applicable for java lambdas, but I'm not sure.

Here is the code. Basically I want to advice Runnable instances. And it works perfectly if I use classes or anonymous class, but it doesn't work if I use lambdas.

```
  @Around("execution(* (com.test..* && java.lang.Runnable+).run())")
  def runnableAspect(pjp: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any = {
    println("Runnable caught")
    pjp.proceed()
  }
```

And here is the test code:

```
package com.test

class Greet {

  def hello(): Unit = {
    println("-----start--------")
    run(new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = println("anonymous class")
    })
    println("------------------")
    run(() => println("lambda"))
    println("-----end--------")

  }

  private def run(r: Runnable) = r.run()

}
```

Output is:

```
-----start--------
Runnable caught
anonymous class
------------------
lambda
-----end--------
```

Is it possible at all? And if it is, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bases on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31098062/5249621) answer.

For Java

```
@Around("execution(void com.test..lambda*(..)) || execution(* (com.test..* && java.lang.Runnable+).run())")
```

For Scala

```
@Around("execution(void com.test..$anonfun*(..)) || execution(* (com.test..* && java.lang.Runnable+).run())")
```